Brzozowski Algebraic Method for converting finite automaton from NFA to DFA
The Brzozowski Algebraic Method is a technique used in automata theory, specifically for constructing the minimal deterministic finite automaton (DFA) from a given nondeterministic finite automaton (NFA). It was introduced by Janusz Brzozowski in 1962 and involves the use of algebraic transformations to simplify and optimize automata.
There are many Implementations of Brzozowski Algebraic Method in different languages:

JavaScript npm install regexgen
Python pip install greenery
OCaml
C++, written by me
Rust, written by me
R, written by me

I was trying to rewrite the OCaml code in Mathematica. The result is consistent.
The Mathematica code written by me is as follows:
Try it online! \$\quad\$ Ref OCaml code for verification.
(* Define regular expression types *)
Clear[EmptyExpr, EpsilonExpr, CarExpr, UnionExpr, ConcatExpr, StarExpr]

(* Simplify regular expressions using simplifications similar to OCaml's simple_re *)
Clear[simplify]

(* Simplify each type of regular expression *)
simplify[EmptyExpr[]] := EmptyExpr[]
simplify[EpsilonExpr[]] := EpsilonExpr[]
simplify[CarExpr[c_]] := CarExpr[c]

(* Simplify Union of expressions, accounting for EmptyExpr and redundant unions *)
simplify[UnionExpr[e_, f_]] := 
  If[e === f, 
    e, 
    (* Simplify Union with EmptyExpr *)
    If[e === EmptyExpr[], 
      simplify[f], 
      If[f === EmptyExpr[], 
        simplify[e], 
        UnionExpr[simplify[e], simplify[f]]
      ]
    ]
  ]

(* Simplify Concat of expressions *)
simplify[ConcatExpr[e_, f_]] := 
  Which[
    e === EpsilonExpr[], f, 
    f === EpsilonExpr[], e, 
    e === EmptyExpr[], EmptyExpr[], 
    f === EmptyExpr[], EmptyExpr[], 
    True, ConcatExpr[simplify[e], simplify[f]]
  ]

(* Simplify Star of expressions *)
simplify[StarExpr[EmptyExpr[]]] := EpsilonExpr[]
simplify[StarExpr[EpsilonExpr[]]] := EpsilonExpr[]
simplify[StarExpr[e_]] := StarExpr[simplify[e]]

(* Ensure the simplified expression is reduced as much as possible *)
simplify[expr_] := expr

(* Recursively simplify with a limit on depth to avoid infinite recursion *)
Clear[recursiveSimplify]
recursiveSimplify[expr_, depth_Integer] := Module[{simplified},
  (* If we've reached a maximum depth, stop the recursion *)
  If[depth > 200, 
    Return[expr], 
    simplified = simplify[expr];
    If[simplified === expr, 
      simplified, 
      recursiveSimplify[simplified, depth + 1]
    ]
  ]
]

(* String representation of the regular expression *)
Clear[sprintRE]
sprintRE[EmptyExpr[]] := "0"
sprintRE[EpsilonExpr[]] := "1"
sprintRE[CarExpr[c_]] := ToString[c]
sprintRE[UnionExpr[e_, f_]] := sprintRE[e] <> "+" <> sprintRE[f]
sprintRE[ConcatExpr[e_, f_]] := "(" <> sprintRE[e] <> ")(" <> sprintRE[f] <> ")"
sprintRE[StarExpr[e_]] := "(" <> sprintRE[e] <> ")*"

(* Brzozowski's Algorithm for NFA to DFA conversion *)
Clear[brzozowski]
brzozowski[a_, b_] := Module[{m, n, i, j, tempA, tempB},
  m = Length[a];
  
  (* Initialize the result matrix b as an empty DFA transition matrix *)
  tempA = a;
  tempB = b;
  
  Do[
    (* Process each state in reverse order *)
    tempB[[n]] = ConcatExpr[StarExpr[tempA[[n, n]]], tempB[[n]]];
    
    Do[
      (* Update the NFA transition matrix tempA *)
      tempA[[n, j]] = ConcatExpr[StarExpr[tempA[[n, n]]], tempA[[n, j]]];
    , {j, 1, n - 1}];
    
    Do[
      tempB[[i]] = UnionExpr[tempB[[i]], ConcatExpr[tempA[[i, n]], tempB[[n]]]];
      
      Do[
        tempA[[i, j]] = UnionExpr[
          tempA[[i, j]], 
          ConcatExpr[tempA[[i, n]], tempA[[n, j]]]
        ];
      , {j, 1, n - 1}];
    , {i, 1, n - 1}];
    
    Do[
      tempA[[i, n]] = EmptyExpr[];
    , {i, 1, n - 1}];
  , {n, m, 1, -1}];
  
  (* Return the regular expression for the DFA starting from state 0 *)
  tempB[[1]]
]

(* Define an example NFA transition matrix *)
a = {
  {EmptyExpr[], CarExpr["a"], CarExpr["b"]},
  {CarExpr["b"], EmptyExpr[], CarExpr["a"]},
  {CarExpr["a"], CarExpr["b"], EmptyExpr[]}
};

b = {EpsilonExpr[], EmptyExpr[], EmptyExpr[]};

(* Convert NFA to DFA using Brzozowski's algorithm *)
dfaExpr = brzozowski[a, b];

Print[sprintRE@dfaExpr, "\n"];

(* Apply recursive simplification and print the simplified result *)
simplifiedDFA = recursiveSimplify[dfaExpr, 0];
Print[sprintRE[simplifiedDFA]]

My question is:
Any suggestion for better organizing my code structure? Should I use Association or DiscreteMarkovProcess to represent automata?
